# Empty CDP Guest List

Tags: cdp

I am trying to view guest details using a fresh Sitecore CDP sandbox instance.  The guest list is empty but the totals at the top show there are 3 guests: 2 customers and 1 visitor.

[image: screenshot of Sitecore CDP. All Guests: 3; Customer: 2; Visitor: 1; Guest type: All; No Results.]

Any idea why no guests are showing up in the guests results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below apis to verify the guest count with type customer and visitor respectively on your tenant:

> https://api-engage-us.sitecorecloud.io/v2/guests?offset=0&limit=10&identityStatus=customer

> https://api-engage-us.sitecorecloud.io/v2/guests?offset=0&limit=10&identityStatus=visitor

**Note**: These api require basic authentication header, api keys for the same can be retrieved from the CDP dashboard.

Since the above aggregate summary that is showing the count of guest is created using segment process which runs as a nightly job , it may be possible those guest/visitor are no more on CDP and these result count will gets updated after 24hrs.